# 403 error on API call, possible authentication issue?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

I want to cry, I really want to cry. I've had this issue for 3 days. I have a POST API in aws lambda, when I test it in aws lambda or in the cli, it works fine. But not when the API is called from my client. I get the following error `POST https://sdigg5u4xb.execute-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/prod/sites 403` and `Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 403
    at createError (createError.js:17)
    at settle (settle.js:19)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (xhr.js:78)`

At first I thought it was to do with CORS but it isnt. Since it's a 403 error it has to be something to do with permissions right? 
I have tried giving my aws users different policies and roles to have permission to do everything but I can't get it working. Please help me before I cry. If anyone needs any of my aws info then just ask

Lambda Code: https://pastebin.com/vWNUQH0T

Calling the API:

import { API } from "aws-amplify";

```
export default (async function submitSite(values) {
  console.log(values);
  return API.post("sites", "/sites", {
    body: values
  })
});
```

Amplify config in my index.js

```
Amplify.configure({
  Auth: {
    mandatorySignIn: true,
    region: config.cognito.REGION,
    userPoolId: config.cognito.USER_POOL_ID,
    identityPoolId: config.cognito.IDENTITY_POOL_ID,
    userPoolWebClientId: config.cognito.APP_CLIENT_ID
  },
  Storage: {
    region: config.s3.REGION,
    bucket: config.s3.BUCKET,
    identityPoolId: config.cognito.IDENTITY_POOL_ID
  },
  API: {
    endpoints: [
      {
        name: "sites",
        endpoint: config.apiGateway.URL,
        region: config.apiGateway.REGION
      },
    ]
  }
});
```

serverless.yml

```
functions:
  # Defines an HTTP API endpoint that calls the main function in create.js
  # - path: url path is /notes
  # - method: POST request
  # - cors: enabled CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing) for browser cross
  #     domain api call
  # - authorizer: authenticate using the AWS IAM role
  createSite:
    handler: CreateSite.main
    events:
      - http:
          path: sites
          method: post
          cors: true
          authorizer: aws_iam
```

Comment: You need to post your Lambda code. The promise is returning with an exception which is unhandled. It could be a permission issue, but unless you handle the exception and `console.log` it (logs in Cloudwatch), you won't be able to know the real issue.

Comment: @Annjawn Thanks for the reply! I added the lambda code. I used pastebin because its pretty long and want to keep it readable.

Comment: We need the code you're using to call the API. Make sure you're sending an Authorization header with the id token.

Comment: @cmaronchick Ive inserted the code where I am calling the api

Comment: Your `authorizer` is `aws_iam`. So you need a `secret key`, `access key` & `token` to authenticate against your API - not the `jwt` token of `Cognito user pool`. How are you authenticating?

Answer (score 0):

It looks as though you're not sending an ID token along with the POST request.

Try adding this to your call:

```
{
    headers: {
       Authorization: cognitoUser.getIdToken().getJwtToken()
    },
    body: values
}
```

cognitoUser will be whatever object name you assign to your user's CognitoUser.

Comment: I get the error "cognitoUser is not defined". I should mention that i dont have a log in system yet in my website. I wanted to get this working before i did that

Comment: I have also added my amplify config from my index.js

Comment: Is there any way I can just hard code in the user api key to the headers in the api call?

Comment: Ok, in that case, is your API using an Authorizer? It should be in the Method Request section of the API.

Comment: I can't seem to find what you're talking about, is it in my code or on aws? I have just inserted to the question the part of my code where the api is defined

Comment: Ok, it's this line:   # - authorizer: authenticate using the AWS IAM role. I haven't used serverless myself, but you are saying that the user has to be in the AWS IAM role, but when you make the API.post call, you are not sending the token that confirms that the user has the right AWS IAM role.

In your AWS Console, you can update this by navigating to API Gateway, selecting your POST method, selecting the Method Request, and changing the Authorizer to None.

Comment: After making this change and running the api via the client, I get this error message `OPTIONS https://sdigg5u4xb.execute-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/prod/sites net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED`

Comment: I assume you have deployed your APIs already, so the next step is to compare the URL you're calling with what is out there. In the left column in API Gateway, select Stages, then select your API. You should see a URL in the right panel. Does it match what you are calling in your code?

Comment: No it doesnt match, i went to my config.js and changed the api gateway url to match the url on aws now i get a 403 error

Comment: Ok, I don't really know how to help you further, except that I highly recommend using a tool such as Postman to test your calls. That's the best I can offer, I'm afraid.

Comment: I got the arn from lambda and put it under the function in serverless.yml, the gateway url matches the code and the aws, now im getting a 500 error. I fee like im making progress haha

Comment: Yes, a 500 error is progress! If you're familiar with CloudWatch you can see if your lambda function is being called and where the error is being thrown. Good luck!

Comment: I'm not familiar with it, but I don't think its being called